# Java: Including jar in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I created a Java project in Eclipse and created a simple class with a main method.

**Problem**: when I run the program(without any server etc), I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException
>       at autoPEC.main(autoPEC.java:6)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>       ... 1 more

**What I tried to solve the problem**: included path to commons-codec.jar in the environment variables JAVA_HOME by putting a semicolon after the jdk path

**Result:** class still does not run

I think that the problem could be that I am not correctly including the classpath. How should I do this?

Comment: Unless you tell us where you put the jar file, and how you configured the project build path in Eclipse, it will be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: Hello, I edited the what I tried part.

Comment: @Javadev: Do you want to solve the problem of running you project in eclipse? Or any other type of execution of your program? Please provide a picture of your project's classpath in eclipse.

Comment: thanks @STaefi. I could solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Google the missing jar and include it in the Java Build path

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this exception is missing of a jar. 
please add the jar(Commons-codec.jar) file needed for this org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException

Download it from here
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi
then put it in your classpath